# Error 3 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)?

Tags: c++

The error that I am getting is coming from a { on the bottom, but did I do something wrong somewhere else that is causing the error?How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdafx.h>

using namespace std;
char Board[9];
//Declare Functions

int main()
{

char Board[9];

//Values for playing board
Board[0] = '0';
Board[1] = '1';
Board[2] = '2';
Board[3] = '3';
Board[4] = '4';
Board[5] = '5';
Board[6] = '6';
Board[7] = '7';
Board[8] = '8';

}
int showBoard();
{ //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS COMING FROM
cout << endl;
cout << Board[0] << "|" << Board[1] << "|" << Board[2] << endl;
cout << "-+-+-" << endl;
cout << Board[3] << "|" << Board[4] << "|" << Board[5] << endl;
cout << "-+-+-" << endl;
cout << Board[6] << "|" << Board[7] << "|" << Board[8] << endl;
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon: `int showBoard()`.

Comment: Note: `showBoard()` won't get the value set to `Board` in `main()` because the global `Board` is shadowed by local `Board` in `main()`.

Comment: Try to avoid global variables. You could use the locally defined `Board` variable in `main`, and pass it as an argument to the functions that need it.

Comment: Your code is hard to read -- please indent your code.  Everything is flushed to the left.  Also, remove `#include <stdafx.h>` -- it isn't necessary in a C++ program.

Comment: I got this same error msg, and upon **thorough** investigation it turned out that I used `UNICODE` as an identifier for an enum value; and MSVC implicitly defines UNICODE as you know; preprocessor macro. I think two things: 1. Macros should be avoided as identifiers in global code or code that does that should avoid participating with other translation unit. 2. There should be a warning if you use a preprocessor macro as a enum, enum value, class, struct, union, template, typedef, namespace, or variable identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A function definition can't contain a semicolon. Remove the semicolon from the end of `int showBoard()`.
2. You need to declare functions before using them, where definitions count as declarations. So write

   ```
   int showBoard();
   ```

   before calling it.
3. `showBoard` will print the (undefined) values of the (uninitialized) array `board` from global scope. To use the array `Board` in `main`, pass it as a `char*` to `showBoard`.

Comment: After I took out the semicolon the origional error was gone, but 14 more errors appeared about this section:

Comment: cout << endl;
    cout << Board[0] << "|" << Board[1] << "|" << Board[2] << endl;cout << "-+-+-" << endl;
 cout << Board[3] << "|" << Board[4] << "|" << Board[5] << endl;
 cout << "-+-+-" << endl;
 cout << Board[6] << "|" << Board[7] << "|" << Board[8] << endl;
 cout << endl;

Comment: @Salpha What errors, for example?

Comment: Error 3 error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier                   Error 4 error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier  There are seven of each of these errors